# My phone has automatically called  *44* twice now, does anybody know what this means?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, dialer-codes

I heard my phone calling `*44*` while it was in my pocket.

Does anybody know what this code means, or do you know what process is *calling* this number?

I have a Samsung Galaxy S running Froyo 2.2.1 and I use a prepaid card.

Comment: Probably not relevant as I see you're in Belgium, but what stood out for me is that "44" is the UK dialling code.

Comment: @GAThrawn Yes , I know, but it really was 44 surrounded with * characters. And just only that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be VAD. It stands for Voice Activated Dialing and is triggered by the service code `*44*`.

I'm not sure why it would do that all by its own without your interaction. An explanation could be that you are using a VAD supporting Bluetooth headset.

Comment: @Octvaian Damiean Thanks for answering - haven't activated AFAIK, nor am I using a Bluetooth headset. Can something like this be triggered by some other device. I was walking on the street and just passing a bus stop with a lot of people (just a (silly) thought ) ?

Comment: I don't think so to be honest. The Bluetooth devices would have to be paired to trigger that function I guess.

Comment: I suspect it could also be activated by the headphone button, or even a short (static discharge) in the headphone jack.  The other thing to look for is an accidental long press on the search button that may be configured for voice actions.

Comment: My Dream/Magic running CM6 don't do this with my headset (Plantronics 220) which supports voice dialing if you hold down the call button - I get the "Voice Dialer" application which tries to guess what I said.

Comment: @BMitch The phone was in my pocket, locked in the home screen and I was just walking on the street. We'll see if it happens again.